# ¿Cómo leer una hoja de estilo, cada vez que el usuario hace un request, aunque no haya sido modificada?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scss

Tengo una página que acepta colores en un un modelo de una BD, la hoja de estilo lee los colores introducidos por el usuario correctamente sólo la primera vez, cuando el usuario modifica un color una segunda vez ya no toma los cambios, cuando modifico manualmente la hoja de estilo es que se actualizan los nuevos colores en la hoja de estilo y necesito que cada vez que haga un request, verifique si hubo un cambio en el modelo de colores y los actualice en la página o si es muy complicado, que actualice esa hoja de estilo cada vez que se haga un request por parte del usuario, hasta ahora he probado desactivar todos los caches que he encontrado y no funcionan, sé que no es la mejor práctica pero incluso con este extremo tampoco funciona.

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache =  nil
config.middleware.delete Rack::Cache
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.compress = false
config.cache_classes = false
```

Básicamente lo que mínimo quiero/necesito es:

*¿Cómo actualizar la hoja de estilo cada vez que el usuario hace un request?*

Answer (score 0):

Ese comportamiento es normal.  Eso pasa porque Rails usa Turbolinks de manera predeterminada.  Turbolinks tiene muchas ventajas, pero una de las consideraciones que hay que tener en cuenta es que los archivos css y js sólo se cargan una sola vez y no se vuelven a recargar.

Tienes dos opciones: dejar de usar Turbolinks y perderte sus beneficios o definir de una vez todos los estilos que vayas a usar y cargarlos en los archivos una sola vez, sabiendo que solo se van a cargar una única vez y quedan en el caché.

https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks